# AWK split file needs to a close

Tags: unix, awk, nawk

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
valcred: requestValCred [up]
 certificate pki_001  [up]
 certificate pki_002  [up]
 certificate pki_003  [up]
 certificate pki_004  [up]
 certificate pki_005  [up]
valcred: internalValCred [up]
 certificate pki_021  [up]
 certificate pki_012  [up]
 certificate pki_103  [up]
 certificate pki_404  [up]
 certificate pki_555  [up]
```

I want to split this into a new text file everytime "valcred" appears. Then, I want to place all the certificates into the file with said valcred.  Below are the contents of one file.  There are around 100 of these files each with a different number of entries.  I get about 20 files when the error occurs.

```
valcred: internalValCred [up]
 certificate pki_021  [up]
 certificate pki_012  [up]
 certificate pki_103  [up]
 certificate pki_404  [up]
 certificate pki_555  [up]
```

Im using this command:

```
nawk '/valcred/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' input_file.txt
```

but this is where it goes wrong.  I run into this error:

```
bash-2.03$ nawk '/valcred/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' input_files.txt
nawk: F21 makes too many open files
 input record number 1743, file input_files.txt
 source line number 1
```

I thought I just need to close the print statement.
Nothing has worked for me.  Can someone help me add a close statement to this that would make it work?  Or an alternative solution?

Comment: Maybe its a unix limit, not awk.  Type 'ulimit -a' to see what the maximum number of open files you can have is.    20 is the old max from the way back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the output file before opening a new one. Also I expect you want to append `>>` to the file `x` rather then overwriting `>` it again and again:

```
nawk '/valcred/{close(x);x="F"++i;printf "" > x}{print >> x;}' input_file.txt
```

Also note, that I'm truncating the file on it's first usage using `printf "" > x`.

Comment: Is there any documentation on the placement of the "close" ? I kept trying to place it later nawk '/valcred/{x="F"++i;}{print > (x); close(print > (x));}'    <--Of course this didn't work but I had other documentation that appeared to lead me to this attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a script file and run it on the text file you want to break up.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { valnum=0 }

/^valcred/ {valnum++
            close(output)
            print $0 > valnum}
/^ certificate/ { print $0 > valnum }
```